# I need an AJAX script to load an URL typed down in an input when submitted

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I did something similar, but not quite what I'm looking for. What I need is to load an url that is being typed down on an input. Eg. I type down "001.xml" and submit it and that is what is going to load.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "", true);
  xhttp.send();

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="demo">
  <h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2>

</div>
  <input type="text" id="url"></input>
  <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Add your code to the question

Comment: I updated it, thanks for the interest @MajedBadawi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, very fast answer, and accurate.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to load? External URL or some query string to your existing page?
Also, you may have to change `<script>` tag where you load jQuery. src should be within script tag.